# NoClassDefFoundError exception in android stuidio

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient

I am not able to resolve below error  :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient;
>                         at com.medicend.jykra.medicend.Async.Parser.LoginParser.hitWS(LoginParser.java:68)
>                         at com.medicend.jykra.medicend.Async.Parser.LoginParser.postData(LoginParser.java:50)
>                         at com.medicend.jykra.medicend.Activity.SignInActivity$LoginAsync.doInBackground(SignInActivity.java:91)
>                         at com.medicend.jykra.medicend.Activity.SignInActivity$LoginAsync.doInBackground(SignInActivity.java:73)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib]]
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                         at com.medicend.jykra.medicend.Async.Parser.LoginParser.hitWS(LoginParser.java:68) 
>                         at com.medicend.jykra.medicend.Async.Parser.LoginParser.postData(LoginParser.java:50) 
>                         at com.medicend.jykra.medicend.Activity.SignInActivity$LoginAsync.doInBackground(SignInActivity.java:91) 
>                         at com.medicend.jykra.medicend.Activity.SignInActivity$LoginAsync.doInBackground(SignInActivity.java:73) 
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
>                         Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location
>   /data/app/com.medicend.jykra.medicend-IiBcrMY7QQm4ixa9RIMICQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
>                         at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>                         at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
>                         at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:101)
>                         at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:75)
>                         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
>                         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
>                         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:164)
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>                         at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
>                         at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
>                         at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
>                         at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
>                         at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
>                         at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
>                         at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: [noclassdeffounderror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: whats the solution for this??

Comment: Without actual codes I can only speculate that the error is caused by using a deprecated code.

Comment: I am not using deprecated codes.It's working fine in my laptop and not in my PC

Answer (score 51):

Add the following to your manifest file under 'application':

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p

Comment: Note: the 'required' attribute requires minimum SDK version 7.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your app uses the legacy `org.apache.http.legacy` client and your app's `targetSdkVersion` is set to `28` or higher.

Consider using `HttpURLConnection` or lowering your `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle`.