# Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.as for (Android P Version)

Tags: android, android-studio, clipboard

I'm trying to open the Android app, it is crashed immediately after opening the page.

I am using the android P version on(Redmi note 7 pro phone) its crashed only for P version.
Its showing `ClipboardService` error and the error is like the following.

> E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.as,
>   application is not in focus neither is a system service for user 0

Please help me to handle this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stuck with same crash, have not found a solution yet. @Mohit any luck ?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to this issue.

Here is the detail.

Device : **Pixel 2**

OS : **Android 10**

Actual issue that led me to the solution was a closer look in the `Logcat` where I found a Deprecation of `HTTP client`, which has already happened in Android Pie. [Documentation LINK](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p)

Solution as per Doc is to add following line inside the application tag in the manifest.

```
<application

<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
 .
 .
 .
</application>
```

This fixed the issue for me, not just in one but more than one places, each one displayed a different error in the `logcat`.

[Additional SOF Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430953/1149398) Thanks to @wongk

Comment: This makes the app crash. To me I was being shown the `ClipboardService` issue  (same as posted by OP) in highlighted but this was not the reason behind the crash.

Comment: Okay. Just confused as to why a networking library with no UI components would be using the Clipboard...

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Oh, to that I'd say the initiation of crash occurred, when I tapped on a `EditText`  Widget on the screen I was repeatedly facing this crash. And this only occurred when I was migrating my office project (It's a well known Shopping App with millions of lines of code), from current `compileSdkVersion = 26` to 28. PS. it may have nothing to do with millions of lines of code BTW. LOL ;)

Comment: Millions eh? Ouch.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt he he exactly, that might sound a bit eerie but true. Thanks for the discussion.